# Reproduce text artist as a transformation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a figure using the following code. My goal is to reproduce the top and bottom axis labels rotated -90 degrees, as well as the untransformed labels below, so the left margin says "male", "female" and the bottom labels are repeated on the right.

I can't find any documentation on `Axes.transData`, which the internet has led me to believe has a `transform` method, which also appears to be undocumented.

[image: Elaborate Punnett Square]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.artist import Artist

plt.close("all")
fig, (ax0) = plt.subplots(1, 1)

dim = 1000

tl_margin = 75
br_margin = 50
tau = 0.90
rho = 0.60

# Rectangle positions
rect_positions = {
    "ffv": {
        "anchor": (0.,) * 2,
        "height": rho * tau * dim,
        "width": rho * tau * dim
    },
    "ffh": {
        "anchor": (rho * tau * dim,) * 2,
        "height": rho * (1 - tau) * dim,
        "width": rho * (1 - tau) * dim
    },
    "mmh": {
        "anchor": (rho * dim + (1 - rho) * tau * dim,) * 2, 
        "width": (1 - rho) * (1 - tau) * dim,
        "height": (1 - rho) * (1 - tau) * dim,
    }
}

label_positions = {
    "female": {
        "sex": {"pos": rho * dim / 2, "symbol": "female"},
        "transmission": {
            "vertical": {
                "pos": rho * tau * dim / 2,
                "symbol": "v"
            },
            "horizontal": {
                "pos": rho * tau * dim + rho * (1 - tau) * dim / 2,
                "symbol": "h"
            }
        }
    },
    "male": {
        "sex": {"pos": rho * dim + (1 - rho) * dim / 2, "symbol": "male"},
        "transmission": {
            "vertical": {
                "pos": rho * dim + (1 - rho) * tau * dim / 2,
                "symbol": "v"
            },
            "horizontal": {
                "pos": rho * dim + (1 - rho) * tau * dim + (1 - tau) * (1 - rho) * dim / 2,
                "symbol": "h"
            }
        }
    }
}

# Colors
primaries = {
    "sex": {
        "female": (255, 0, 255),
        "male": (0, 0, 255)
    },
    "transmission": {
        "vertical": (0, 255, 255),
        "horizontal": (255, 255, 0)
    }
}

alpha = 0.6

# Plot
ax0.set_xlim(-tl_margin, dim + br_margin)
ax0.set_ylim(-br_margin, dim + tl_margin)

ax0.set_aspect(1)
ax0.set_xticks(())
ax0.set_yticks(())

# margins
ax0.hlines((0, dim), 0, dim)
ax0.vlines((0, dim), 0, dim)

# Rectangles
for key, value in rect_positions.items():
    ax0.add_patch(
        Rectangle(
            value["anchor"],
            value["height"],
            value["width"]
        )
    )

# sex ratio lines
ax0.hlines(rho * dim, -tl_margin, dim + br_margin, color="black", linestyle="--")
ax0.vlines(rho * dim, -br_margin, dim + tl_margin, color= "black", linestyle="--")

# vertical transmission lines
ax0.hlines(
    (
        tau * rho * dim,
        rho * dim + tau * (1 - rho) * dim
    ),
    0, 
    dim + br_margin,
    color="black"
)
ax0.vlines(
    (
        tau * rho * dim,
        rho * dim + tau * (1 - rho) * dim
    ),
    -br_margin, 
    dim,
    color="black"
)

# Margin labels
label_ypos = -25
for angle in (0., -90.,):
    transform = ax0.transData + Affine2D().rotate_deg(angle)
    for sex, sex_label in label_positions.items():
        ax0.text(
            sex_label["sex"]["pos"],
            dim - label_ypos, sex_label["sex"]["symbol"],
            color="black",
            va="center",
            ha="center",
            transform=transform,
        )
    
for sex, sex_label in label_positions.items():
    for angle in (0., -90.,):
        transform = ax0.transData + Affine2D().rotate_deg(angle)
        for mode, symbol in sex_label["transmission"].items():
            ax0.text(
                symbol["pos"],
                label_ypos, 
                symbol["symbol"],
                color="black",
                va="center",
                ha="center",
                transform=transform
                )
```

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html

Comment: I have looked at that as well. I'm not able to figure out what I'm doing differently that isn't working.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your issue properly. But if you don't use "transform=..." and instead of it just write: "rotation=90" then your text will otate 90 degrees.

Comment: I am trying to rotate the text in the margins around the entire center of the plot, so that they are duplicated in the other margins, rather than simply rotating the text in place.